# Accept a request to subscribe to a private telegram channel via aiogram

Tags: python, telethon, aiogram

There is a task to confirm subscription requests in the telegram channel using a bot.
If anyone knows how to do this through aiogram or telethon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are bound methods `approve()` and `decline()` that can be used with `chat_join_request_handler()`

```
@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def join(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
    await update.approve()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem like this:

```
    @dp.chat_join_request_handler()
    async def echo(message: types.Message):
         await bot.approve_chat_join_request(
                      message.chat.id,                                   
                      message.from_user.id)
```